# Why is the Current Working Directory when accessing a text file not the Directory where my program is saved?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite new to Python and am studying through a book. I'm just trying to run filereader.py which just opens and reads a text file. This text file is inside the same folder as the python code.  but when I run it, this error appears:

```
Error:
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pi_digits.txt'
  File "C:\Users\lcsan\Desktop\python_work\Chapter 10\filereader.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open('pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
```

Here's the code:

```
Filereader.py:

with open('pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
print(contents)
```

I tried importing os and using the os.getcwd() function to see where the program is searching for the text file.

This is the original Dir: (censored some parts)
C:\Users\*****\Desktop\python_work\Chapter 10'

This is the result of the os.getcwd() function:
C:\Users\*****\Desktop\python_work'

It seems that it is one directory behind the intended directory. Is there no other way to access it through relative path or do I really have to indicate the absolute path through os.chdir()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current directory will be whatever the current directory was when you executed the script.  Running a Python script does not change the directory.  If you need to access files in the same directory as the script, you can do that:

```
scriptpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname( __file__ ))
with open(scriptpath + '/pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but if you are running code by terminal your terminals working directory should be same with codes directory.

**if code's path dir1/dir2/code.py**

**files in directory:**

*code.py s*

*sample.txt*

**sample.txt content**

```
text
text
text
text
this is a sample text
```

**code:**

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
lines = open("sample.txt")
print(lines.read())
```

**when ran from top directory:**

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\dir1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dir2/code.py", line 3, in <module>
    lines = open("sample.txt")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample.txt'
```

**when ran from same directory:**

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\dir1\dir2>python code.py
C:\Users\User\Documents\dir1\dir2
text
text
text
text
this is a sample text
```